# Hörmander's proof of: $ u, f \in C(\Omega) $, $ D_j u = f $ in distribution sense $ \implies $ $ D_j u = f $ classically.

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence, distribution-theory, convolution, weak-derivatives

I am looking at the following theorem, which can be found in Hörmander's *Linear Partial Differential Operators*, and I have two questions about the proof.

[image]

Here is Hörmander's Theorem 1.2.1, in case you were wondering:

[image]

> **Question 1:** Why is it sufficient to prove the
>   theorem for $ u $ having compact support in $ \Omega $?

Here is what I make of the first two lines of the proof. Let's suppose for a moment that Theorem 1.4.2 is already proven for $ u \in C_{0}^{0}(\Omega) $. If we take $ \tilde{u}, f \in C(\Omega) $ and $ \chi \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega) $ and if we assume $ D_j \tilde{u} = f $ in the distributional sense, then
$$ D_j(\chi \tilde{u}) = D_j(\chi) \tilde{u} + \chi f $$
in the distributional sense. Since $ D_j(\chi) \tilde{u} + \chi f $ and $ \chi \tilde{u} $ are continuous and the latter has compact support, the theorem implies that $ D_j(\chi \tilde{u}) = D_j(\chi) \tilde{u} + \chi f $
holds also in the classical sense. Now, if we can show that this implies $ \chi (D_j \tilde{u}) = \chi f $ (in classical sense), then it follows that $ D_j \tilde{u} = f $ in the classical sense because the choice of $ \chi $ was arbitrary; and so it's indeed sufficient to prove the theorem for $ u $ continuous of compact support. But how to show that
$$ D_j(\chi \tilde{u}) = D_j(\chi) \tilde{u} + \chi f \:\: \text{in classical sense} \implies \chi (D_j \tilde{u}) = \chi f \:\: \text{in classical sense}? $$ Is this what Hörmander had in mind at all?

By the way, I have also come across this proof [$u$ continuous and the weak derivative $Du$ continuous $\Rightarrow$ $u \in C^1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787716/u-continuous-and-the-weak-derivative-du-continuous-rightarrow-u-in-c1), which seems to get by without first proving the result for $ u \in C_{0}^{0} (\Omega) $ before treating the general case $ u \in C(\Omega) $. It appears to me that, instead of Hörmander's Thm. 1.2.1, the author of the proof has used the *(iii)* of the following theorem, which may be found in the appendix of L.C. Evans' PDE book.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Question 1, Hörmander might have had a [partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity) in mind. There are $\chi_k \in C_0^\infty$ such that $\sum_k \chi_k \equiv 1$ on all of $\Omega$. Then
$$
D_j u = D_j ((\sum_k \chi_k) u) = \sum_k D_j (\chi_k u),
\quad
\quad
f = (\sum_k \chi_k) f = \sum_k (\chi_k f).
$$
Thus, if we can show that $D_j(\chi_k u) = \chi_k f$ in the distributional sense implies the same in the classical sense, then $D_j u = f$ in the distributional sense implies the same in the classical sense. Also, if we can show this generally when $u$ has compact support then it follows that it is valid specifically when $D_j (\chi_k u) = \chi_k f$.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question 1:**

Let $ \chi \in C_0^\infty (\Omega) $. If $ \tilde{u}, f \in C(\Omega) $, then $ \chi \tilde{u} $ and $ D_j(\chi) \tilde{u} + \chi f $ are continuous functions with compact support. We recall also that the chain rule for distribution derivatives implies that

$$ D_j(\chi \tilde{u}) = D_j(\chi) \tilde{u} + \chi D_j \tilde{u} \:\:\: \text{(in the distributional sense).} $$
Hence, if Hörmander's Thm. 1.4.2 holds true for continuous functions $u$ with compact support and if $ D_j u = f $ in the distributional sense, then
$$ D_j(\chi \tilde{u}) = D_j(\chi) \tilde{u} + \chi f \:\:\: \text{(in the classical sense).} \tag{1}$$

If we assume that $ \text{supp} \chi \neq \emptyset $, then [If the product of continuous $f$ and compactly supported smooth $\chi$ is $C^1$, then $f$ is $C^1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281084/if-the-product-of-continuous-f-and-compactly-supported-smooth-chi-is-c1) implies that on the interior of $ \text{supp} \chi $ we have
$$ D_j(\chi \tilde{u}) = D_j(\chi) \tilde{u} + \chi D_j \tilde{u} \:\:\: \text{(in the classical sense).} \tag{2}$$

Combining (1) and (2), we get $ \chi D_j \tilde{u} = \chi f $ (in the classical sense) on $ \text{int} (\text{supp} \: \chi) $. This is true for any compactly supported smooth $ \chi $ with $ \text{supp} \chi \neq \emptyset $ and in particular for $ \chi_{x_0} \in C_0^\infty(\Omega) $ with $\chi(x_0)=1$, $ x_0 \in \Omega $. (Such a function can be constructed for any $ x_0 \in \Omega $ using the standard mollifier). Therefore we may conclude that $ D_j \tilde{u} = f $ on the whole of $ \Omega $.