# If the product of continuous $f$ and compactly supported smooth $\chi$ is $C^1$, then $f$ is $C^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, distribution-theory

How to prove the following claim?

> Let $\Omega $ be an open subset of $ \mathbb{R}^n $, $ u \in C(\Omega) $ and $ \chi \in C_0^\infty (\Omega) $ with $ \text{supp} \: \chi \neq \emptyset $.
>
> If $ \partial_j (\chi u) \in C(\Omega) $, then $ \partial_j u $ exists (and is continuous) on the interior of $ \text{supp} \: \chi $.

N.B. The claim in the title follows immediately from this.

Comment: As stated, the claim is trivially false: Just take $\chi=0$. I suppose you want to check the quantors ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you! Just corrected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interior of the support of $\chi$: The function $\frac 1\chi$ is smooth. Hence $u$ is $C^1$, being the product of two $C^1$ functions: $$u=(u\chi)\frac1\chi.$$

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem of calculus allows us to write, for $ x_0 \in \Omega $,

\begin{equation}
(\chi u) (x_0 + te_j) - (\chi u)(x_0) = \int_{0}^{t} \partial_j (\chi u) (x_0 + se_j) \: ds ,
\end{equation}
where $e_j$ is the $i$-th standard unit vector in $ \mathbb{R}^n$ and $ t $ is a real parameter. Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus again along with the quotient rule, we obtain that for $ x_0 \in \text{int} (\text{supp} \: \chi) \subset \Omega $

\begin{align}
 \partial_j u (x_0) &= \left. \frac{d}{dt} u(x_0 + te_j) \right \vert_{t=0} \\
&= - \chi (x_0) \: u(x_0) \frac{\partial_j \chi (x_0)}{\lvert \chi (x_0) \rvert^2} + \partial_j (\chi u)(x_0) \\
&= - \frac{u(x_0)}{\chi (x_0)} \partial_j\chi(x_0) + \partial_j (\chi u)(x_0) .
\end{align}

Hence $ \partial_j u $ exists and is clearly finite on the set $ \text{int} (\text{supp} \: \chi) $. q.e.d